# Modify a property of one random NSPoint and put the new version back in an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray that I am adding a random number of CGPoints that will eventually make a UIBezierPath using the standard [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]; I need to access a random element from that array and modify just the y property of that element and place it back in the same random spot it was pulled from. My problem is finding that random spot to put the modified element back into. The logic below is crashing at runtime with an "index out of range" exception of NSRangeException. It makes sense to me, I think the pointer is pointing to a completely different address of memory somewhere far outside the range of the ordered array, but I am not seeing how I can get the new modified element back into the array at the same random spot if was pulled from. Below is my failed attempt to do so...

```
NSValue *randomPoint = [self.midPointsArray objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [self.midPoints2 count]];
CGPoint newPoint = [randomPoint CGPointValue];
newPoint.y = newPoint.y + 20;
[self.midPointsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:randomPoint withObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:newPoint]];
```

Comment: People need to be in the habit of attempting to debug their own code before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the random index:

```
int randomIndex = arc4random() % [self.midPoints2 count];
NSValue *randomPoint = [self.midPointsArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
CGPoint newPoint = [randomPoint CGPointValue];
newPoint.y = newPoint.y + 20;
[self.midPointsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:randomIndex withObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:newPoint]];
```

Comment: Thank you Avt. I laughed when I read this. Can't believe I missed it. Thanks again.